# (Unity) Get RGB of mouse position?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rgb

HS student here wondering how to get the RGB value of the mouses location in Unity? I've looked around everywhere and there are either simple ways that don't work or that are unanswered or extremely complicated methods that don't relate to what I'm trying to do.

Basically I tracked the position of the mouse, and am now trying to obtain the RGB value of the image under it, which isn't working?

Here's my code, I tried 2 different methods which I thought would work but don't (I know I don't need both a Raw Image and Texture2D, it's just that's what each method tried).

```
public Text cords = null;
int mousex;
int mousey;

public RawImage pic;
public Text textColor = null;
public Texture2D image;

void Start () {

}


void Update () {
    mousex = (int)Input.mousePosition.x;
    mousey = (int)Input.mousePosition.y;
    cords.text = "X: " + mousex + "   Y: " + mousey;

    //Color32 color = (pic.texture as Texture2D).GetPixel(mousex, mousey);
    Color32 color = image.GetPixel(mousex, mousey);
    //textColor.text = color.ToString();
    Color32 Hovercolor;
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        Hovercolor = image.GetPixel(mousex, mousey);
        textColor.text = Hovercolor.ToString();
    }


}
```

Comment: *"which I thought would work but don't"* What doesn't work?

Comment: I thought either one of the methods would work, using a 2DTexture or using a RawImage however, neither of them work.

Comment: You still haven't explain what's not working. What's suppose to happen for it to be considered working and what's happening now? Do you get any error? Don't just say it's not working.

Comment: The idea is that the textbox I have setup (textColor) is supposed to display the RGB values. There are no error messages in Unity or VS, it's just that the text is not changing to the RGB of the pixel the mouse is on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use [Texture2D.GetPixel](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixel.html) get pixel from  texture.Note that:

> The texture must have the read/write enabled flag set in the texture
>   import settings, otherwise GetPixel will fail. GetPixel is not
>   available on Textures using Crunch texture compression.

And I've found that you use Input.mousePosition as the index to seek pixel in texture.You also should note that once they donnot match：

> If the pixel coordinates are out of bounds (larger than width/height
>   or small than 0), they will be clamped or repeated based on the
>   texture's wrap mode.

Comment: Thanks, I thought there was an error elsewhere, not in the prefab. Enabling read/write worked!

Comment: @stishedemail Please accept answer if that solved your problem.